# Unable to Match X0 - Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I am unable to get a Regex to behave properly can anybody see why?

```
Regex: ^[T|X0]?\d{2,8}-\d{2}$
```

Should be (1): either a T or X0, (2): Two to Eight Digits, (3): Hyphen, (4): 2 Digits

This should allow the following examples

```
1: T10000001-01 (Works)

2: X010000001-01 (Doesn't work)
```

For some reason the zero after the X is not working. If I remove the Zero from the example it works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining a class

You should do this instead, with a non capturing group

```
^(?:T|X0)\d{2,8}-\d{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `T` `|` OR `X0` inside  capturing or non-capturing group.

```
^(T|X0)\d{2,8}-\d{2}$
```